# MASVS 1.12: "Endpoints verify that clients use up-to-date version"

Tags: mobile, owasp

In the current [OWASP MASVS](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-masvs) (as of now v0.9.3) we can find the following requirement for MASVS-L2 in *Security Verification Requirements*:

> **MASVS 1.12:**
>   "Remote endpoints verify that connecting clients use an up-to-date version of the mobile app."

I'm wondering how central the point about 'endpoint verifying [...] clients' is. For example, if a client does a version check via service call, would this be sufficient in your eyes? (I.e. the client calls a service which tells him the the 'minimal required version', and the client can then force an update if necessary.)

The way I see it, if the client is compromised we can't really trust *any* info that it sends to the endpoint (such as its version number for a server-side check as proposed by MASVS 1.12). And if the client is *not* compromised, then it shouldn't matter if the version check is actually done client-side instead of server-side, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to some of the authors of the OWASP MASVS document on [their slack channel](https://owasp.slack.com/messages/C3XEJHB7T/) I think the answer boils down to:

- It doesn't matter if this check is done client-side or server-side
- Its goal simpy is to be able to force users to update off of old versions.
- An attacker attacking the app could circumvent/beat this version check in many different ways independent of whether the check is done client-side or server-side.